# Calculating 'posted-ago' time is not working correctly with strtotime() and date() functions in php

Tags: php

This is the function is used to calculate 'posted-ago'.

```
function actionTime( $ptime )
{
    $estimate_time = time() - $ptime;
    echo $estimate_time.'<br>';
    if( $estimate_time < 2 )  return 'Just now';
    $condition = array(
    12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
    30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
    24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
    60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
    60                      =>  'minute',
    1                       =>  'second');
    foreach( $condition as $secs => $str )
    {
        $d = $estimate_time / $secs;
        if( $d >= 1 )
        {
            $r = floor( $d );

            return $r . ' ' . $str . ( $r > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

function calling:

```
$time=actionTime(strtotime($prow['time']));
```

$prow['time'] in DB is: 2017-03-14 18:08:45

**Problem:**

When I print the result, 'Just now' is showing for many minutes.

> $estimate_time

is showing negative number like around -15000 when echoed.

**Elaboration:**

When echoed the following:

```
echo "time():".time()." posted time:".strtotime($prow['time']);
```

It showed:

> time(): 1489496166
>   posted time:1489511325

Current time is less than posted time. Why?

Comment: Please show us what you are passing into the function in `$prow['time']`

Comment: You could probably achieve this more simply by using the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: If `$estimate_time` is showing a negative number like `-150000` you must be entering a date that is larger that NOW i.e. a date or time that is after now not before now

Comment: @Sumanth Yedoti may i know you posted time zone ? because still the time is not crossed your posted time that 's y you get negative value

Comment: @Sumanth Yedoti it look like your posted time in db is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send time alone in the function actionTime(strtotime($prow['time'])).

Make sure to send complete date and time like actionTime(strtotime('2016-12-12 12:01:00));

Comment: Please see below. I did that before calling the function.

Comment: Yes i can see. Can you give me exact original $prow['time'] value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally... :D

I solved the problem  by removing the attribute **on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** for the time column and inserted php time(). Problem solved.

Still I dont know why this problem occurred.

I just wanted you to know how i solved the problem with this simple trick.

Thank you.
*(Im not pro-coder)*